# Print lexicographically smallest palindrome after filling each '.' character, if it possible to construct one. Print -1 otherwise in python

Tags: python

I could do this same task in C++; But I am learning python newly, I just want to try out the similiar code I used in C++ - but I am having some problems in this code, Can you help out what wrong I did;

```
 def constructPalin(string,length):
  i = 0
  j = length - 1; 
  while(i < j):
    if (string[i] == string[j] and string[i] != '.'):
        continue
    elif (string[i] == string[j] and string[i] == '.'):
        string[i] = 'a'
        string[j] = 'a' 
        continue 
    elif (string[i] == '.'):
        string[i] = string[j]
        continue 
    elif (string[j] == '.'):
        string[j] = string[i]
        continue
    else:
        string="-1"
        return string
    i=i+1
    j=j-1
  return string
string=input() 
length = len(string)
string=constructPalin(string,length)
print(string)
```

I am getting correct output only for -1;Help me out in other cases

Comment: Please give an example of input and expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Python won't allow you to modify a string (they are 'immutable'), but you can turn them into lists, modify them and then turn them back into strings. Looks difficult or slow, but not at all.

Second, 'continue' in Python is used scarcely. A good code shouldn't have it. That's why you have elif's and else's after all.

Third, Don't use an 'if' if you are not doing anything within it.

Fourth, learn pythonic tricks (like the == or the = lines below), that's the real difference from other languages. Makes code clearer in most of the cases.

Cheers

```
def constructPalin(string, length):
    i = 0
    j = length - 1
    string = list(string)  # turn it to list, as strings can't be modified
    while (i <= j):  # '<=' to consider a '.' in the middle
        # if (string[i] == string[j] and string[i] != '.'):  # only use 'if' when you need to
        if (string[i] == string[j] == '.'):  # both equal to '.'
            string[i] = string[j] = 'a'  # turn them to 'a'
        elif string[i] != string[j]:  # not equal, can still be fixed filling the '.'s?
            if (string[i] == '.'):
                string[i] = string[j]
            elif (string[j] == '.'):
                string[j] = string[i]
            else:  # hopeless
                string = "-1"
                return string
        i = i + 1  # if you use "continue", you'll never reach these lines
        j = j - 1  # ... and the program loops forever
    return "".join(string)  # turn it back to string
```

Answer (score 0):

If the first and the last string matches, its index value should get updated!

```
if (string[i] == string[j] and string[i] != '.'):
    i=i+1
    j=j-1
```

Comment: @Flaming_Dorito that part was not necessary, I removed it.